# Explain mapping IP addresses

Tags: java, reactjs, frontend, backend

I have project that I want to host on local server and I encountered with strange thing .
I have my back-end part running on 8080 port and front-end on 3000 port , and I was playing around with hosting separately back-end and front-end. And here is the thing that I don`t understand :
When I host like this

```
        back-end :  localhost:8080
        front-end : 192.168.50.41:3000
```

or

```
        back-end : 192.168.50.41:8080
        front-end : localhost:3000
```

It works completely fine (I mean all requests from front-end successfully get to back-end )

BUT if host like this

```
        back-end : 192.168.50.41:8080
        front-end : 192.168.50.41:3000
```

it throws a CORS error , however I changed CORS configuration in my **application.yml** file like this

```
        cors:
          allowed-origins: http://192.168.50.41:3000

          allowed-endpoints: > 
           /api/v1/auth/login,
           /api/v1/auth/register,
```

and this is my security config

```
             @Bean
              public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    ;`
```

Maybe someone encountered with something like this and know the solution for this , because I think that I miss smth in my config

Comment: allowed-origins: http://192.168. **50.41** :3000, vs 192.168. **30.28**  why ? **50.41** vs **30.28**

Comment: oh i forget to change this, thanks

Comment: I changed it to the correct one but it still doesn`t work , Is there a possibility that local server can only receive requests from outer "world" but inside of it it block requests between ports inside of it??

Comment: Check how many network interfaces you have? What is the corresponding ip address? ? Check whether the backend has received the corresponding request?

Comment: I changed ip address to 192.168.50.41 and backend receives reqeusts only from Postman at this point and if i want to send from front-end it throws this **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.50.41:8080/api/v1/auth/login' from origin 'http://192.168.50.41:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: `cors: allowed-origins: http://192.168.50.241:3000` is `241` a typo? You're referencing `41` everywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is basically the ports which is 8080 is for primary web servers.secondary web servers don't use it .

`Trend Micro Antivirus products may use port 3000 UDP to communicate with their servers.`
so you cannot use port which already define for another

likely the port 3000 is port of for primary/default HTTP you might use http .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).